# How do I populate a select tag with a hash and properly save the value to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, hash, form-helpers

I'm attempting to setup a form for a model that contains a select box populated from a collection in the hash.

Specifically, my employee model has a hash of roles:

```
ROLES = {1 => "Lead", 2 => "Engineer", 3 => "Intern" }
```

And a validator:

```
validates_presence_of :role
```

Ideally, I'd like to populate a select box in a form using this information. Something such as :

```
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
    <%= label_tag :role, "Role" %>
    <%= f.select :employee, :role, Employee::ROLES %>
<% end %>
```

Although I can display the values in the select box, the data isn't serialized. Instead, I receive the validation message that the "Role can't be blank."

My controller's create method looks like this:

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
  if @employee.save
    redirect_to employees_path, :notice => "Successfully created a new employee."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Ultimately, my question is how do I populate the select box using the hash in the model and properly save the value of the select box to the column on the employee model in the database?

Comment: it should be done with an Array

Comment: What's the generated output of the select tag?

Comment: <select id="user_role" name="user[role]"><option value="Lead">1</option><!-- snip --></select>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'll be easier if you follow the advice and use an array to store your Roles, but you don't have to... We can just convert it into an array at render time

```
ROLES = {1 => "Lead", 2 => "Engineer", 3 => "Intern" }

puts ROLES.map{|r| [ r[0], r[1] ]}
=> [[1, "Lead"], [2, "Engineer"], [3, "Intern"]]
```

The select_tag expects an array of [Name,id] (Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })

(Note that you don't want :employee here)

```
<%= f.select :role, Employee::ROLES.map{|role| [ role[1], role[0] ]} %>
```

If you don't want to both with this:

```
ROLES = ["Lead", "Engineer", "Intern"]

<%= f.select :role, Employee::ROLES %>
```

Comment: I'm fine using an array - didn't mean to imply I was strongly pursuing the use of a hash. But thanks for this :).

Answer (score 0):

More succinctly:

```
<%= f.select :role, Employee::ROLES.invert %>
```